# Sourcing Veal bacon

Tags: bacon, veal

I'm a chef in Scotland and I've been trying to source 'veal bacon' to no avail.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: "south". (ok, I's sorry, that's terrible, but I couldn't resist...)

Comment: I've never come across veal bacon but is it not practical for a chef such as yourself to buy in veal loin steaks and cure it yourself?

Comment: On closing:  http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/what-types-of-sourcing-questions-should-be-allowed-revisit-march-2013-plea

Answer (score 1):

I think making your own will be the easiest, if you have a good source for veal (which is nigh on impossible to get here in the Midwest USA, which, ironically, is where a lot of veal is produced.  We just can't buy it anywhere.).

As to the cut, if you want your "bacon" to be more like Canadian bacon, which is a cured loin, get the loin.  If you want it to be more like rashers (or what we call bacon in the States), get the belly cut.

Curing it will require some kosher salt and some pink salt (aka #2 Curing Salt) and some plastic zipper bags.  Depending on how large the cut is, it will take about 3-7 days in the fridge.

Answer (score 0):

As Jennifer S said, you can make your own. If you're not willing to do that, you can try to visit farmers markets. I've found online that it's sold on some farmer markets in the US. I'm guessing you asked your meat supplier(s) already?

[Here](http://chowhound.chow.com/topics/756232) I've found a comment which points to three manufacturers that produce it:

- Swissland Packing Co., of Ashkum, III.
- Catelli Brothers of Collingswood, N.J.
- Strauss Veal, Inc. of Franklin, Wis. SYSCO (the largest foodservice distributor in the country distributes veal bacon to the foodservice marketplace)

I've come up empty-handed when searching for veal bacon in Europe.